# How can I tell Wicket that it's being accessed through Apache with SSL Termination so that I can avoid mixed-content errors when loading scripts?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, wicket-6

My wicket app is running behind an Apache Proxy configuration with SSL termination.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerName my-domain-name
  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:49161/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:49161/
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain-name/fullchain.pem
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-domain-name/privkey.pem

  RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https

  Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Using this configuration, I can actually access the application through https. So this part is working fine.

The problem is when I use additional plugins in Wicket, for example the Google Map wicket extension. This will insert a link to a script in the html which results into a mixed-content error.

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://my-domain-name/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I assume it's using http there, because it thinks the page is being served over http. This is the reason why I added the X-Forwarded-Proto part in the virtual host config, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

I also tried to tell tomcat that the https scheme is used by updating the HTTP Connector in server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="false" 
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Any ideas what I could do on the Wicket Application layer to tell it the application is actually served over https and not http?

Thank you!

Kristof.

Answer (score 0):

In the case with WicketStuff GMap3 module you can provide the scheme you prefer as a constructor parameter: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/d517667103a1cd97acc86ee51c2c733e79d9234f/gmap3-parent/gmap3/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/gmap/GMapHeaderContributor.java#L69

Otherwise you can use `X-Forwarded-Proto` request header to decide whether the application is behind the proxy or not.

Comment: Hi martin-g, thanks for the suggestion. I'll try the GMap3 module ... although the problem I have goes beyond GMap, I also have it with other plugins that use scripts in the front-end. A generic solution like the X-Forwarded-Proto would be great, but as mentioned in the question, that's not working. The question is, is Apache properly setting the Header, is tomcat passing it on, or is Wicket ignoring it?